# Как оставить два ноля после запятой в числе при переводе строки в число?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно получить число с 2 знаками после запятой. Использую +num.toFixed(2).
Все работает с числами, у которых есть дробная часть. В целых же числах, при переводе из строки в число, два ноля обрезается, и я получаю просто целое число. ("9.00" -> 9). Есть вариант получить число 9.00?

Comment: Чем **число** `9` отличается от `9.00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак это то что вы видите. Все числа в JavaScript это number. JavaScript numbers всегда хранится как double согласно стандарту IEEE 754.

так что не разницы в JS между 9 и 9.00 но на выводе в строку вы можете использовать форматирование и точность.

.toFixed()

.toPrecision()

подробнее читайте [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp)

Answer (score 4):

> Есть вариант получить число 9.00?

Да, убрать "плюс" из `+num.toFixed(2)`. И использовать получившуюся строку там, где Вам нужны два нуля после точки.